# How to use PostgreSQL JSON containment to match sub-item without explicitly including the entire hierarchy?

Tags: postgresql, json

In the PostgreSQL documentation on the JSON "@>" containment operator at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-json.html#JSON-CONTAINMENT, it states:

> Because JSON containment is nested, an appropriate query can skip
> explicit selection of sub-objects.

It then gives an example that seems very strongly to suggest that you can just specify the lower-level matching object and it will find that object wherever it may be within the nested JSON object hierarchy. But I have not had any success with any approach except for full explicit specification of the entire structure. For instance, the test query below always returns "Nope." even though there is an exact match for the given object just one level down.

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN '{"docs": {"tags":"happy"}}'::JSONB @> '{"tags":"happy"}'::JSONB THEN 'YES!!' 
    ELSE 'Nope.' 
END;
```

What I would really like to get to in the end is a situation where I can find all occurences of a lower-level object such as `{"tags":"happy"}` wherever it may occur within arrays of nested objects like this:

```
{fields: [
    {"name":"color",   "value":"yellow", "tags":"happy"}, 
    {"name":"texture", "value":"rough",  "tags":"sad"},
    {"name":"parts",   "value":[{"article":"skirt", "tags":"happy"}, {"article":"socks", "tags":"sad"}]}
]}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You interpret the tip from the documentation wrong: like the example there shows, the “appropriate query” has to contain the path to the object that you are trying to match.

To find an object somewhere inside a `jsonb`, you need the JSONPATH operator `@?` and the wildcard accessor `.**`:

```
SELECT JSONB '{"docs": {"tags":"happy"}}' @? 'strict $.**.tags ? (@ == "happy")';
```

What you can't get, to the best of my knowledge, is the actual path where `tags` was found.